# Running Multiple Gunicorn Instances for Low-Traffic Websites

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

I've been exploring the use of Gunicorn and Nginx to serve Django websites, and it's generally recommended for its performance benefits. However, I have a question regarding running multiple websites on the same server with Gunicorn.

If I want to run multiple websites, it seems that I need to run separate instances of Gunicorn for each site. My concern is whether this approach will unnecessarily consume CPU and RAM resources, especially if the websites have low traffic.

In the past, I've used a LAMP stack to run multiple websites without requiring dedicated processes for each site. This makes me wonder if the modern approach with Gunicorn and Nginx is better in terms of resource usage and efficiency.

Could anyone shed some light on this? Am I missing something in understanding the benefits of running multiple Gunicorn instances for multiple websites, even if they have low traffic?

I appreciate any insights or experiences you can share.

Thanks in advance!